# PHP exec() causes connection timeout when using nohup

Tags: python, php

I have a class executing a python script using the exec() function in PHP. It gives me a timeout even tho i'm using nohup to run in in the background.

Server is running on 4GB memory and is an LXC container with centOS 8. Web engine is nginx.

Any ideas?

```
<?php

class Deployment {

  private $clusterName;
  private $vendor;
  private $nodeIP;
  private $password;
  private $cmd;

  public function task($clusterName, $vendor, $nodeIP, $password) {

    $this->cmd = escapeshellcmd('python3 /usr/share/nginx/python/script.py --ip '.$nodeIP.' --password '.$password);

    // Execute Job here
    exec($this->cmd);
  }

  // Method used to execute the python engine
  private function exec($cmd = null){
     if(!$cmd){
         throw new Exception("No command given");
         die('No command given');
     }
     shell_exec("/usr/bin/nohup ".$cmd." > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
  }
}
```

**The error i'm getting:**

```
2020/11/25 01:00:26 [error] 109#0: *5 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.10.225, server: _, request: "POST /dev/html/deploy.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock", host: "172.16.10.202", referrer: "http://172.16.10.202/dev/html/deploy.php"
```

Comment: Could be a subnet mask issue in your network config

Comment: I don't think so. It does actually run the script and does what its supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I renamed my private function to exec() without thinking about this beeing an actual built-in PHP function.

This is the part of code I changed:

```
// Execute Job here
    $this->execTask($this->cmd);
  }

  // Method used to execute the python back-end engine
  private function execTask($cmd = null){
     if(!$cmd){
         throw new Exception("No command given");
         die('No command given');
     }
     shell_exec("/usr/bin/nohup ".$cmd." > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
  }
```